# How to Specify $docker build --network="host" mode in docker-compose at the time of build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-build

While building docker image like `docker build -t name:tag --network="host"` so it will Set the networking mode for the RUN instructions during build (default "default")

So I am trying to build Docker image with DOKCER-COMPOSE:

```
version: '3'
services:
  ezmove-2.0:       
    network_mode: "host"
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
```

So as per above compose file I am trying to build image but how to Specify --network="host" mode in docker-compose at the time of build

Comment: I think, I have to keep docker container build process seperate from docker-compose, if --network="host" option is not present in docker-compose!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

[@dkanejs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47077519/96588) is right, and here is how you use it (the version number is important):

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  my_image:
    build:
      context: .
      network: host
```

Comment: @I0b0 thanks for answer, but 'network: host' will works only in version '3.4'

Comment: @Dhairya That's why I said "the version number is important"…

Answer (score 7):

Looks as though the option was [added in the latest version](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/4997) but is nowhere to be found in the `docker-compose` [online documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build).

Comment: You can find it [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network)