# How to copy subdirectories artifacts by jenkins Copy Artifact Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cicd

I am trying to use the following jenkins plugin to copy front application build artifacts to subsequent jobs.

[Copy Artifact Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/copyartifact/)

Application artifacts are output to the following directories:

```
/build
  /test
  /js
  /css
  404.html
  index.html
```

So I put the following in the Jenkinsfile of the subsequent job:

```
script {
   try {
     env.FRONT_BRANCH=params.FRONT_BRANCH
     copyArtifacts(projectName: "../front-app/", selector: specific(params.FRONT_BUILD_NO), filter: 'build/**/*', target: 'front', fingerprintArtifacts: false)
   } catch (hudson.AbortException e) {
    println(e)
   }
   sh 'ls front'
}
...
```

But, console output is here:

```bash
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls front
build
```

I expect the following output results:

```bash
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls front
  test
  js
  css
  404.html
  index.html
```

I don't want to copy the build directory, which is the root directory of the artifacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my own projects I'm using a similar solution, but i am using the jenkins built-in stash/unstash option.

[stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074457/how-to-specify-docker-build-network-host-mode-in-docker-compose-at-the-time)
[unstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074457/how-to-specify-docker-build-network-host-mode-in-docker-compose-at-the-time)
[stackoverflow article correct usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050248/correct-usage-of-stash-unstash-into-a-different-directory)

Your problem description looks pretty similar to the use case stash and unstash would provide for you.