# Restart a docker container when it is higher than from a certain of memory limitation?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I want to have a policy in my `docker-compose` which a docker container memory usage will be higher than the amount of a certain memory limitation it restarts.

This is what I have done so far:

```
version: '3'

services:
    modbus_collector:
        build: .
        image: modbus_collector:2.0.0
        container_name: modbus_collector
        restart: unless-stopped
        deploy:
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 28M
```

I was expecting that to be restarted when the container memory usage exceeds `28M`, but when I monitor docker containers by `docker stats` I see that this container memory usage grow up and not happens about restart!

I also tried by `restart: always` but the result was the same.

---

[UPDATE]:

With version 2 it works fine with `mem_limit:`. But it fails while using version 3, putting them under `deploy` section doesn't seem worthy unless I am using swarm mode.

Even on version `2.1`, I have a problem in restarting the container: limitation applied correctly, but when the container memory usage grows up, this limitation prevents of that but I expected instead of decrease memory it will restart that container.

```
version: '2.1'

services:
    modbus_collector:
        build: .
        image: modbus_collector:2.0.0
        container_name: modbus_collector
        restart: unless-stopped
        mem_limit: 28m
```

Comment: According [to compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#deploy) the deploy configuration is only supported in Docker Swarm. Are you using Swarm mode?

Comment: No, and I'm using docker-compose version `3`. Is there any other manner to handle this purpose?

Comment: [Compose file reference for version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources) suggests to use [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources). I am not sure if version 2 compose file elements work in version 3 compose files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify Memory & CPU limit in docker compose version 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345235/how-to-specify-memory-cpu-limit-in-docker-compose-version-3)

Comment: @Markus I tried this answer but not worked.

Comment: I did some research in the mean time and found out that those constraints are not being supported in version 3 compose files. You must use version 2.

Comment: You are right, Now I switched to version `2.1` with `mem_limit: 28m` and it applied correctly, but when the container memory usage grows up, this limitation prevents of that but I expected instead of decrease memory it will restart that container.

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4513) has some bits of information on why version 2 is needed.