# How to specify max cpu and ram in docker compose 3.7

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How to specify max cpu and ram in docker compose 3.7.?

My compose file is:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  mongodb_container:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: psw
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: admin
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod --auth
    volumes:
      - ./data-docker/mongo:/data
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify Memory & CPU limit in docker compose version 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345235/how-to-specify-memory-cpu-limit-in-docker-compose-version-3)

Comment: @Domin nnope, its ignoring this resources, In `docker stats` there is a still more memory then I set in docker-compose file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the cpu and memory limit using the deploy option

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  mongodb_container:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: psw
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: admin
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod --auth
    volumes:
      - ./data-docker/mongo:/data
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 150M
```

But what you need to make that works is to run the docker-compose using **--compatibility** flag `docker-compose --compatibility up --build`

Comment: Thank you `--compatibility`