# Xdebug runs out of memory with PHPUnit

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpunit, out-of-memory, xdebug

Maybe memory overflow isn't the correct description of what happening, but the point is: PHPUnit eat all of the memory and then dies the container.

Here is my `phpunit.dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ --allow-untrusted gnu-libiconv
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so php

ENV PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=1G
ENV PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 512M
ENV PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE: 512M

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo

RUN apk add --no-cache libpng libpng-dev && docker-php-ext-install gd && apk del libpng-dev

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        freetype \
        libpng \
        libjpeg-turbo \
        freetype-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        jpeg-dev \
        libwebp-dev \
        libjpeg \
        libjpeg-turbo-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd \
        --with-freetype=/usr/lib/ \
        --with-jpeg=/usr/lib/ \
        --with-webp=/usr

RUN NUMPROC=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null || 1) \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j${NUMPROC} gd

RUN apk add --no-cache sqlite-libs
RUN apk add --no-cache icu sqlite git openssh zip
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps icu-dev libxml2-dev sqlite-dev curl-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
        bcmath \
        curl \
        ctype \
        intl \
        pdo \
        pdo_sqlite \
        xml
RUN apk del .build-deps

RUN docker-php-ext-enable pdo_sqlite

# Add xdebug
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS
RUN apk add --update linux-headers
RUN pecl install xdebug-3.1.5
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
RUN apk del -f .build-deps

# Configure Xdebug
RUN echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.mode=coverage" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.log=/var/www/html/xdebug/xdebug.log" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.discover_client_host=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

RUN echo memory_limit = -1 >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-memlimit.ini;
```

I use `docker-compose run --rm phpunit --coverage-html` to start PHPUnit.

When I run PHPUnit without `--coverage-html` option, it runs smoothly. But with this option it start tests and new dots showing slowly and slowly and then stops showing new dots. But the processor usage grow up to 100%, memory usage also growing up to 100%, then swap is runs out, and then the container dies.

Is there any option to tell PHPUnit the maximum usable memory size or something other trick to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about setting memory limit for PHPUnit, but, if you want to limit the memory/CPU usage of your docker, you can set in in docker-compose file similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345235/how-to-specify-memory-cpu-limit-in-docker-compose-version-3).

Just curious: Is the memory and CPU spike happening in non-docker environment as well?

Comment: If the memory usage is limited then happens same thing, because xdebug eats all of the memory. I tried without docker with 16 GB RAM, and same thing...
Until the question asked I wrote to the developer of XDEBUG, didn't get any positive answer so I changed to PCOV. It works faster and use much more less memory.

Comment: So it has to do with XDEBUG and not docker then. Please edit the question to reflect the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase your memory limit manually via editing the line `ENV PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=1G`. If you application is the reason for the high memory consumption, you should consider to fix memory leaks.

Comment: I tried and not help.